# Loading CSV data to Snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Column splits into multiple columns when trying to load the following data in to SnowFlake table since its CSV file.

Column Data :

```
{"Department":"Mens 
Wear","Departmentid":"10.1;20.1","customername":"john4","class":"tops wear","subclass":"sweat shirts","product":"North & Face 2 Bangle","style":"Sweat shirt hoodie - Large - Black"}
```

Is there any other way to load the data in to single column.

Comment: What is your fileformat / your copy into-statement?

Comment: You can create a table with a **VARIANT** column and insert that data parsed as JSON. So [VARIANT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#variant) is here and [PARSE_JSON](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_json.html) is here.

Comment: As @Marcel said, please share the whole row, not just a column of data - and how you are loading

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be use a different delimiter instead of comma in your CSV file. If it's not possible, then you can ingest the data using a non-existing delimiter to get the whole line as one column, and then parse it. Of course it won't be as effective as native loading:

```
cat test.csv 
1,2020-10-12,Gokhan,{"Department":"Mens Wear","Departmentid":"10.1;20.1","customername":"john4","class":"tops wear","subclass":"sweat shirts","product":"North & Face 2 Bangle","style":"Sweat shirt hoodie - Large - Black"}

create file format csvfile type=csv FIELD_DELIMITER='NONEXISTENT';        

select $1 from @my_stage (file_format => csvfile );

create table testtable( id number, d1 date, name varchar, v variant );

copy into testtable from (
select 
split( split($1,',{')[0], ',' )[0], 
split( split($1,',{')[0], ',' )[1], 
split( split($1,',{')[0], ',' )[2], 
parse_json( '{' || split($1,',{')[1]  )  
from @my_stage (file_format => csvfile )
);

select * from testtable;


+----+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |     D1     |  NAME  |                                V                                |
+----+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 2020-10-12 | Gokhan | { "Department": "Mens Wear", "Departmentid": "10.1;20.1", ... } |
+----+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```